# Trigger that selects from table that is being deleted

Tags: oracle

This trigger ends up raising an error regardless of the if statement values. I'm basically selecting from the same table the delete is occurring on and it's not liking it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_schedules
    AFTER   DELETE
    ON SCHEDULES
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
lParentCond   schedules.cond_code%type;
lParentActive   schedules.active_flag%type;
lError  exception;


BEGIN
    if :OLD.thread is not null then

        select cond_code, active_flag
        into lParentCond, lParentActive
        from schedules where schedule_seq = :old.thread;

        if lParentCond = 'OK' and lParentActive in ('*', 'F') then

            raise lError;

        end if;

     end if;



EXCEPTION
    when lError then 
        raise;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;


END delete_schedules;
```

Any ideas of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting the dreaded 'MUTATING TABLE' error. Oracle doesn't allow us to fetch data from the table on which the trigger is defined in an AFTER trigger - but in this case you don't need to because the 'old' values are already available. Rewrite your trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER delete_schedules
    AFTER DELETE
    ON SCHEDULES
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if :OLD.thread is not null AND
     :OLD.COND_CODE = 'OK' and
     :OLD.ACTIVE_FLAG in ('*', 'F')
  then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Invalid combination of COND_CODE and ACTIVE_FLAG');
  end if;
END delete_schedules;
```

This assumes (based on the use of a singleton SELECT in the question) that there's only one row in SCHEDULES for the given THREAD value. If that's not the case there are other work-arounds, including using a COMPOUND TRIGGER.

Best of luck.